# Calculate the value of \$\zeta(s)\$

Tags: code-golf, math

### Challenge

Given an integer, \$s\$, as input where \$s\geq 1\$ output the value of \$\zeta(s)\$ (Where \$\zeta(x)\$ represents the [Riemann Zeta Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function)).

### Further information

\$\zeta(s)\$ is defined as:

$$\zeta(s) = \sum\limits^\infty_{n=1}\frac{1}{n^s}$$

You should output your answer to 5 decimal places (no more, no less). If the answer comes out to be infinity, you should output \$\infty\$ or equivalent in your language.

Riemann Zeta built-ins are allowed, but it's less fun to do it that way ;)

### Examples

***Outputs must be exactly as shown below***

```
Input -> Output
1 -> ∞ or inf etc.
2 -> 1.64493
3 -> 1.20206
4 -> 1.08232
8 -> 1.00408
19 -> 1.00000
```

### Bounty

As consolation for allowing built-ins, I will offer a 100-rep bounty to the shortest answer which **does not** use built-in zeta functions. (The green checkmark will still go to the shortest solution overall)

### Winning

The shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: This challenge had such potential... Until you allowed builtins...

Comment: @HyperNeutrino Yep, I posted because I saw the challenge allowed builtins. FGITW

Comment: Is "to a precision of 5 decimal places" strict? (i.e. can we output to more precision?) If not the test cases should show 6dp really.

Comment: @JonathanAllen I've cleared up the rounding spec

Comment: @BetaDecay (sigh no ping) should an input of `19` *really* output the text `1.00000`? Wouldn't `1` or `1.0` be valid? It seems you have made it into a chameleon challenge.

Comment: What if our language does not have infinities?

Comment: @Adám (I spelled his name incorrectly, so it did not ping him) and you will have to find a workaround if your language does not support infinities

Comment: Is the domain all reals?  Or just inputs `≥1`?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt *Given an **integer**, `s`, as input where `s>=1`*

Comment: Ah whoops, I missed that part.  Sorry!

Comment: @BetaDecay Which answer is the bounty for?

Comment: Above image For series is not seen, Tex in ![] is void...

Comment: @RosLuP What do you mean? The image still shows for me

Comment: @BetaDecay in my cellphone Window Phone the image for zeta formula is not seen

Comment: @RosLuP Hm, I'm not sure what's wrong there. It's taking the image from Wikipedia

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Mathematica, <s>9</s> <s>7</s> 11 bytes

```
Zeta@#~N~6&
```

Explanation:

```
Zeta@#       (* Zeta performed on input *)
      ~N     (* Piped into the N function *)
        ~6   (* With 6 digits (5 decimals) *)
          &  (* Make into function *)
```

[image: Mathematica result]

Without builtin:

## Mathematica, 23 UTF-8 bytes

```
Sum[1/n^#,{n,∞}]~N~6&
```

Thanks to Kelly Lowder

Comment: `N@*Zeta` saves two bytes.

Comment: `@*` is the (left) composition operator: `f@*g` denotes a function whose value at the argument `x` is `f[g[x]]`.

Comment: @BetaDecay For `1` it outputs `ComplexInfinity`, and it rounds to `5` places. (e.g. `1.64493`)

Comment: @MartinEnder How does the `*` work?

Comment: @NoOneIsHere see Greg's comment

Comment: @Uriel For `19` it outputs `1`. Editing.

Comment: `Sum[1/n^#,{n,∞}]~N~6&` is 23 Bytes, without using the built-in.

Comment: @NoOneIsHere your answer uses `N~5` but your explanation uses `6`.

Answer (score 9):

## Javascript, <s>81</s> <s>70</s> <s>66</s> 65 bytes

```js
s=>s-1?new Int8Array(1e6).reduce((a,b,i)=>a+i**-s).toFixed(5):1/0
```

### Runnable examples:

```js
ζ=s=>s-1?new Int8Array(1e6).reduce((a,b,i)=>a+i**-s).toFixed(5):1/0

const values = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 19 ];
document.write('<pre>');
for(let s of values) {
  document.write('ζ(' + s + ') = ' + ζ(s) + '\n')
}
```

Comment: Why call it Z? The zeta symbol is a valid function name in JS, and you don't need it to be golfed.

Comment: Replace `Array(1e6).fill()` with `[...Array(1e6)]`, and replace the first `(s)` with `s`

Comment: @QPaysTaxes Good point! Unicode variable names ftw!

Comment: @ConorO'Brien Huh, I never realized that Array trick (I thought sparse arrays didn't iterate but I guess I was wrong). Thanks!

Comment: @Frxstrem Note that ζ takes two bytes

Comment: ```s=>[...Array(1e6)].reduce((a,b,i)=>s>1>i?a:i**-s+a,0).toFixed(5)```

Answer (score 7):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>22</s> 21 bytes

Look ma, no built-ins! -1 thanks to ngn.

Since Dyalog APL does not have infinities, I use [Iverson's proposed notation](http://www.jsoftware.com/papers/APLDictionary1.htm#2a2).

```apl
{1=⍵:'¯'⋄5⍕+/÷⍵*⍨⍳!9}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///Pyq1JPFR24RqQ9tHvVut1A@tV3/U3WL6qHeqtv7h7UAhrUe9Kx71bla0rIWoVTDkAlNGEMoYQplAKFMIZQGhDC0B)

`{` anonymous function:

`1=⍵:` if the argument is one, then:

`'¯'` return a macron

`⋄` else

`!9` factorial of nine (362880)

`⍳` first that many integers **i**ntegers

`⍵*⍨` raise them to the power of the argument

`÷` reciprocal values

`+/` sum

`5⍕` format with five decimals

`}` [end of anonymous function]

Comment: `1E6` -> `!9`­­

Answer (score 5):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>112</s> <s>101</s> <s>94</s> 84 bytes

Thanks for the golfing tips from ceilingcat.

```c
n;f(s){float r;for(n=98;n;r+=pow(n--,-s));printf("%.5f",r+pow(99,-s)*(.5+99./--s));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XcvRCoMgGIbhc69ChMHvTEfbgkS6GBH@CMxCHTuIbn1udTQ8fd7vc3J0rpRgEBLf0C8202hwiRAG3ZtgohjW5Q1BykYmzs0ap5AR2EV1yJoojqj10a6gOqG1uslzuJfZTgE42QilCO3v@soJGOPmhHsNjxqeNfQ1tPpfdlI@Dr0dU5F@/gI)

Comment: The question has been edited. You can output language native infinity symbols.

Comment: @2501 I reverted back to the previous answer, although I'm still quite a few bytes away from your solution.

Comment: @ceilingcat `f(1)` doesn't seem correct.

Comment: [83 bytes](https://tio.run/##XctLCoMwFIXhuasIgcINeYhtBUNwMRK4IsREEqUDsUtvqh2VTL/zHytHa3P2BiGxHV0YVhINhgi@153xJvJ@CS/wUgqZGDNLnPyKQG@qRSoiB9VyrVX9Ptf6KrUWV3fkeZg8sGqvCEFozue2JqCUmR/cS3iU8CyhK6HR/3JU@WPRDWPK0s1f "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 5):

### C, <s>74</s> <s>70</s> 69 bytes

```
n;f(s){double z=n=0;for(;++n>0;)z+=pow(n,-s);printf("%.5f",z/=s!=1);}
```

Compile with `-fwrapv`. It will take some time to produce an output.

See it [work here](https://ideone.com/vt8QIv). The part `++n>0` is replaced with `++n<999999`, so you don't have to wait. This keeps identical functionality and output.

Comment: Does `float` work?

Answer (score 5):

## TI-Basic, 16 bytes (no builtins)

```
Fix 5:Σ(X^~Ans,X,1,99
```

Comment: You really need to go up to about 150000 to get the answer right for Ans=2, which would take upwards of half an hour to calculate on an 84 Plus CE. Also, you could multiply by (Ans-1)^0 somewhere to get an error for Ans=1, TI-Basic's closest representation of infinity!

Comment: @pizzapants184 I'm fully aware that 2, 3, etc. might take more than 99 iterations. You can achieve this functionality by replacing `99` with `E9` where E is the scientific E, i.e. representing 10^9. (Or obviously something smaller like E5). Understanding that E99 is generally used for positive infinity also allows for this functionality theoretically, if the upper bound of the summation was `E99`. Emulators can provide this much faster than a physical calculator. Thanks for your thoughts :)

Comment: I don't think this counts as displaying infinity. It won't even throw an error if you added 1 infinitely, due to floating-point imprecision.

Answer (score 3):

## [Julia](https://julialang.org/), 36 bytes

```
x->x!=1?@sprintf("%.5f",zeta(x)):Inf
```

Answer (score 3):

## C,<s>129 130</s> 128 bytes

```
#include<math.h>
f(s,n){double r=0;for(n=1;n<999;++n)r+=(n&1?1:-1)*pow(n,-s);s-1?printf("%.5f\n",r/(1-pow(2,1-s))):puts("oo");}
```

it uses the following formula

[image: \zeta(s) = \frac{1}{1-2^{1-s}}\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^s}}]

test and results

```
main(){f(2,0);f(1,0);f(3,0);f(4,0);f(8,0);f(19,0);}

1.64493
+oo
1.20206
1.08232
1.00408
1.00000
```

Comment: Why this equation instead of `Σ(1/(n^s))`? It seems much more complicated...

Comment: @BetaDecay because it seems to me more fast in find the result; here there is the range for sum s in 1..999, in the 'Σ(1/(n^s)) ' there is need s in the range 1..10^6

Comment: I see. FYI, simply `oo` is fine, you don't need to specify it as positive

Comment: [85 bytes](https://tio.run/##XcvRCoIwFIDhe59CBsI55Sm2ChrDh5HREUGPshkF4qu3pKvY1Q8f/J4671NiiLXgysPULmVwPAWQxlrriMRhODYglTkY0niYpxdITRHdHHpZGFR1urGqwxk0Pd6z2RMR0W1pbHsBLNaiLBn0PjyXCEqh@4HJ4ZLDNYd7Dtr@y1akj@eh7WKiYfwC "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: @ceilingcat you can write one other entry for this question... it seems I remember here without math.h header it not link...

Answer (score 3):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), <s>133 129 120</s> 117 bytes

```rust
fn f(s:f64){let mut y@mut n=0.;while n<999.{n+=1.;y-=f64::powf(-1.,n)/n.powf(s)}print!("{:.5}",y/(1.-(1.-s).exp2()))}
```

[Try it online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bZAxDoJAEEV7T7FQ7UQYXETDspJ4FQs2ksBIYAkSQukpbCj0UN5GINgYivnJvMzP_5nnq6wrMwzv2mg3_NSamOZVpI8BdFliWF4b1p4npXiHqrmmWcLoJKXEjraxQNW68XgdRcWt0dwV6BB4hPNWQV-UKRmL212Eh952Wo8LdKepAJN74XMA6JfwxxieX1Li0G3YWEMgqNmfkcVBzcxfYfsVFqywcIUJ-QeXMr-PfAE)

Thanks to @Steffan for -9.

Slightly golfed less

```rust
fn f(s:f64){
  let mut y@mut n=0.;
  while n<999.{
    n+=1.;
    y-=f64::powf(-1.,n)/n.powf(s)
  }
  print!("{:.5}",y/(1.-(1.-s).exp2()))
}
```

Comment: `n+=1.;}` no need for the semicolon

Comment: and `\n` can be a literal newline

Comment: You can save even more using a newer version than on TIO: [ATO](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bdA7DoJAEADQ3lMsVDsBBhfR8JHEq1iwkQRGwi4BQig9hQ2FHsrbCAQbQzFTvMwv83xVtdLj-K61dIJPK4lJriJ58qHPU82KWrPuMmdK9hg3tyxPGZ3DMMSerERg3FnJVB1F5b2R3BFokyUQXMIFFAxllZE2uNlHeBxMu3O5QGcOBZi2pccBYFj3P6b9xTUjDv2OTZdMk-KlPyeDQ7yYt2GHDfM3LNgwEf7heszvKV8)

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 21 bytes

```
q?'%.5f'2e5:G_^sYD}YY
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@19or66qZ5qmbpRqauUeH1cc6VIbGfn/vzEA)

#### Explanation

Input `1` is special-cased to output `inf`, which is how MATL displays infinity.

For inputs other than `1`, summing the first `2e5` terms suffices to achieve a precision of 5 decimal places. The reason is that, from direct computation, this number of terms suffices for input `2`, and for greater exponents the tail of the series is smaller.

```
q         % Input (implicit) minus 1
?         % If non-zero
  '%.5f'  %   Push string: format specifier
  2e5:    %   Push [1 2 ... 2e5]
  G       %   Push input again
  _       %   Negate
  ^       %   Power. element-wise
  s       %   Sum of array
  YD      %   Format string with sprintf
}         % Else
YY        %   Push infinity
          % End (implicit)
          % Display (implicit)
```

Answer (score 2):

## R, 54 bytes

```
function(a){round(ifelse(a==1,Inf,sum((1:9^6)^-a)),5)}
```

Finds the sum directly and formats as desired, outputs `Inf` if a is 1. Summing out to `9^6` appears to be enough to get five-place accuracy while still being testable; `9^9` would get better accuracy in the same length of code.  I could get this shorter if R had a proper ternary operator.

Comment: `function(a)round("if"(a-1,sum((1:9^6)^-a)),5)` is a few bytes shorter.

Comment: Yes, but it throws an error if a = 1.  `function(a)round("if"(a-1,sum((1:9^6)^-a),Inf),5)` works and is still shorter than my original solution.

Comment: Oh yes of course! I forgot to include the `Inf`, that's what I get for typing code into the comment box directly...

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3: 67 bytes (no built-ins)

```
f=lambda a:"∞"if a<2else"%.5f"%sum([m**-a for m in range(1,10**6)])
```

Nothing fancy, only uses python **3** because of the implicit utf-8 encoding.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#@59mm5OYm5SSqJBopfSoY55SZppCoo1Rak5xqpKqnmmakmpxaa5GdK6Wlm6iQlp@kUKuQmaeQlFiXnqqhqGOoYGWlplmrCYXSCYRJBNtqGOkY6xjomOhY2gZa8XFWVCUmVeioJGmkaip@f8/AA) with test cases.

Comment: `def f(a):` is two bytes less than `f=lambda a:`...

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/) + SciPy, 52 bytes

```python
lambda n:'%.5f'%zeta(n,1)
from scipy.special import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcpBCsIwEAXQfU7xN6WJDIVYBS30JOoi1gQH2iQk2dSD9Ri9UhTf@sW1vIPv676N9zqb5fky8EPbdGfXNh9bjPSklXApLMgTx7XL0U5sZvASQyqHWmwuGSNumnAk9IQT4ULQ14cQLiQw2OO/BoGfmNgXuW@Slapf)

Comment: Does this output `∞` for input `1`?

Comment: Similarly, is this rounding to five decimal places?

Comment: @ETHproductions It outputs `inf` which is allowed.

Comment: Super late, but couldn't you just use `zetac(n)` instead of `zeta(n,1)`?

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 23 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ȷ6Rİ*⁸S÷Ị¬$ær5;ḷỊ?”0ẋ4¤
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@39iu1nQkQ1ajxp3BB/e/nB316E1KoeXFZlaP9wB4tk/aphr8HBXt8mhJf///zcCAA)**

#### How?

- Sums the first million terms
- Divides by `0` when `abs(input)<=1` to yield `inf` (rather than `14.392726722864989`) for `1`
- Rounds to 5 decimal places
- Appends four zeros if `abs(result)<=1` to format the `1.0` as `1.00000`
- Prints the result

```
ȷ6Rİ*⁸S÷Ị¬$ær5;ḷỊ?”0ẋ4¤ - Main link: s
ȷ6                      - literal one million
  R                     - range: [1,2,...,1000000]
   İ                    - inverse (vectorises)
     ⁸                  - link's left argument, s
    *                   - exponentiate
      S                 - sum
          $             - last two links as a monad:
        Ị               -   insignificant? (absolute value of s less than or equal to 1?)
         ¬              -   not (0 when s=1, 1 when s>1)
       ÷                - divide (yielding inf when s=1, no effect when s>1)
           ær5          - round to 10^-5
                      ¤ - nilad followed by link(s) as a nilad:
                  ”0    -   literal '0'
                    ẋ4  -   repeated four times
                Ị?      - if insignificant (absolute value less than or equal to 1?)
              ;         -       concatenate the "0000" (which displays as "1.00000")
               ḷ        - else: left argument
                        - implicit print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 50 bytes

```
{$_-1??(1..1e6).map(* **-$_).sum.fmt('%.5f')!!∞}
```

Answer (score 1):

## PARI/GP, <s>27</s> 26 bytes

```
\p 6
s->trap(,inf,zeta(s))
```

Answer (score 1):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), 14 bytes (no builtins)

```
┴¿Å'∞{◄╒▬∩Σ░7<
```

Note that in the TIO link, I have substituted `◄` for `►`, which pushed \$10^6\$ instead of \$10^7\$. This is because the version submitted here timeouts for all test cases. This results in the answers for 3 and 8 to be off by 1 decimal place. However, there are way bigger 1-byte numerical literals in MathGolf, allowing for arbitrary decimal precision.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATcAyP9tYXRoZ29sZv//4pS0wr/DhSfiiJ574pa64pWS4pas4oipzqPilpE3PP//MQoyCjMKNAo4CjE5)

### Explanation

```
┴                check if equal to 1
 ¿               if/else (uses one of the next two characters/blocks in the code)
  Å              start block of length 2
   '∞            push single character "∞"
     {           start block or arbitrary length
      ◄          push 10000000
       ╒         range(1,n+1)
        ▬        pop a, b : push(b**a)
         ∩       pop a : push 1/a (implicit map)
          Σ      sum(list), digit sum(int)
           ░     convert to string (implicit map)
            7    push 7
             <   pop(a, b), push(a<b), slicing for lists/strings
```

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 64 bytes

```javascript
s=>[...Array(1e6)].reduce((a,b,i)=>s>1>i?a:i**-s+a,0).toFixed(5)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYxLDoIwAAX3nOLtaKE04i9@AsaNl0AWFYqpIdS0QDTGa3EMroQlcfkmM@8hemELo55t1OhSTuOQTDZJM8752RjxJrHc0pwbWXaFJESwG1M0SW0ap@okDioIIhsKtqC81Rf1kiXZ0KnQjW3Ri7qTFgkyxAxLhhXDmmHHEO@RH71KG1LLFha6@ssUHw@Yc11LXus78ceB@AidFMKn7mwejjnVgWvjU@87/QA)

Pointed in Frxstrem's

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 19 bytes

```
ċ[₆(n⁰eĖ⅛)¾∑øḋ7Ẏ|\∞
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJQIiwiIiwixItb4oKGKG7igbBlxJbihZspwr7iiJHDuOG4izfhuo58XFziiJ4iLCIiLCI0Il0=)

No builtins used, used 4 bytes on the decimal places

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 26 bytes

```
⁵*5İH+µŒṘḣ7
⁴!Rİ*³SÇµ’İµ’?
```

[Don't try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/@ocauW6ZENHtqHth6d9HDnjIc7FptzPWrcohh0ZIPWoc3Bh9sPbX3UMPPIBjBl////fyMA) with this link! (Since this uses 16!~20 trillion terms, running on TIO produces a MemoryError)

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/@ocauW6ZENHtqHth6d9HDnjIc7FptzgQTNgo5s0Dq0Ofhw@6GtjxpmHtkApuz///9vBAA) with this link instead. (Uses 1 million terms instead. Much more manageable but takes one more byte)

Returns `inf` for input 1.

**Explanation**

```
⁵*5İH+µŒṘḣ7    - format the output number
⁵*5İH+         - add 0.000005
      µŒṘ      - get a string representation
         ḣ7    - trim after the fifth decimal.

⁴!Rİ*³SÇµ’İµ’? - main link, input s
           µ’? - if input minus 1 is not 0...
⁴!R            -   [1,2,3,...,16!] provides enough terms.
   İ           -   take the inverse of each term
    *³         -   raise each term to the power of s
      S        -   sum all terms
       Ç       -   format with the above link
               - else:
        µ’İ    -   return the reciprocal of the input minus 1 (evaluates to inf)
```

Out of the 26, bytes, 7 are used for computation, 12 are for formatting, and 7 are for producing `inf` on zero. There has to be a better golf for this.

Comment: `ȷ6` is a numeric literal of a million, removing the factorial workaround.

Answer (score 0):

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), 33 bytes (no built-ins)

```
_:^:('*'&e.)7j5":1#.1%[^~1+i.@1e6
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8FOJT31NAVbKwV1BR0FAwUrINbVU3AO8nFbWlqSpmtxUzHeKs5KQ11LXS1VT9M8y1TJylBZz1A1Oq7OUDtTz8Ew1QyicIcmV2pyRr5DmpqenYKhgpGCsYKJgoWCoSVEesECCA0A)

```
_:^:('*'&e.)7j5":1#.1%[^~1+i.@1e6
                           i.@1e6  NB. integers up to 1e6
                         1+        NB. add one
                      [^~          NB. nʸ for each in 1..1e6
                    1%             NB. reciprocal of each
                 1#.               NB. sum the result
            7j5":                  NB. format each result, width of 7, 5 decimal places
  ^:                               NB. if
    ('*'&e.)                       NB. '*' is in the formatted result
                                   NB. (": fills with *'s if the width is too small)
_:                                 NB. return an infinity
```

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 20 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
i'∞ë6°LImzO5.ò¾4×«7£
```

4 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) are used to account for edge case \$n=1\$, and 9 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) to round to five decimal places (6 of which for edge case `1.00000`)..

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/U/1Rx7zDq80ObfDxzK3yN9U7vOn/f0MA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##AUMAvP9vc2FiaWX/dnk/IiDihpIgIj95/2kn4oiew6s2wrBMeW16TzUuw7LCvjTDl8KrN8Kj/30s/1sxLDIsMyw0LDgsMTld).

**Explanation:**

```python
i          # If the (implicit) input-integer is 1:
 '∞       '#  Push "∞"
ë          # Else:
 6°        #  Push 10 to the power 6: 1,000,000
   L       #  Pop and push a list in the range [1,1000000]
    Im     #  Get the power of the input on each integer
      z    #  Calculate 1/value for each
       O   #  Sum everything together
 5.ò       #  Round to 5 decimal places
    ¾4×    #  Push a string of 4 zeros: "0000"
       «   #  Append it to the result
        7£ #  Pop and leave just the first 7 characters: "1.abcde"
           # (after which the result is output implicitly as result)
```