# Implement the Riemann R function

Tags: code-golf, math, number-theory

The Riemann R function is as follows:

$$R (x)=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{\mu (n) \text{li}\left(x^{1/n}\right)}{n}.$$

This uses the [Möbius function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function) as well as the [logarithmic integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function).

From Wikipedia, the Möbius function is defined so that for any positive integer \$n\$,  \$μ(n)\$ is the sum of the primitive nth roots of unity. It has values in \$\{−1, 0, 1\}\$ depending on the factorization of \$n\$ into prime factors:

- \$μ(n) = +1\$ if \$n\$ is a square-free positive integer with an even number of prime factors.
- \$μ(n) = −1\$ if \$n\$ is a square-free positive integer with an odd number of prime factors.
- \$μ(n) = 0\$ if \$n\$ has a squared prime factor.

The logarithmic integral is defined as:

$$\operatorname{li}(x) = \int_2^x \frac{dt}{\log t}.$$

An alternative way to compute the Riemann R function is via the [Gram series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1506980/could-someone-explain-how-the-gram-series-relates-to-riemanns-function). That is:

$$R(x) = 1 + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(\ln x)^k}{k k!\zeta(k+1)}.$$

The function \$\zeta()\$ is the [Riemann zeta function](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/119596/calculate-the-value-of-zetas?rq=1).

## Challenge

Write code that computes \$R(x)\$ for \$x\$ up to \$10^{31}\$. The output may have a margin of error of up to 1.

## Test cases

Here are the answers for \$10^i\$ for \$i = \{1, 2, \dots, 31\}\$.

```
1 4.56458314100509023986577469558
2 25.6616332669241825932267979404
3 168.359446281167348064913310987
4 1226.93121834343310855421625817
5 9587.43173884197341435161292391
6 78527.399429127704858870292141
7 664667.447564747767985346699887
8 5761551.86732016956230886495973
9 50847455.4277214275139488757726
10 455050683.306846924463153241582
11 4118052494.63140044176104610771
12 37607910542.2259102347456960174
13 346065531065.82602719789292573
14 3204941731601.68903475050075412
15 29844570495886.9273782222867278
16 279238341360977.187230253927299
17 2623557157055978.00387546001566
18 24739954284239494.4025216514448
19 234057667300228940.234656688561
20 2220819602556027015.40121759224
21 21127269485932299723.733864044
22 201467286689188773625.159011875
23 1925320391607837268776.08025287
24 18435599767347541878146.803359
25 176846309399141934626965.830969
26 1699246750872419991992147.22186
27 16352460426841662910939464.5782
28 157589269275973235652219770.569
29 1520698109714271830281953370.16
30 14692398897720432716641650390.6
31 142115097348080886394439772958.0
```

Your code doesn't need to be fast, but ideally it should complete in under a minute.

## Related challenges

- [Möbius function](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/69993/the-m%C3%B6bius-function?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Riemamn zeta function](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/119596/calculate-the-value-of-zetas?rq=1)

---

## Precision

You will need 128 bit floats to represent the output.   In C `__float128` from `quadmath.h` is the simplest way (`long double` will most likely be 80 bits).  Other languages may have standard libraries to support 128 bit floats (e.g Decimal in Python). [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenges are judged *per language* so there is no penalty in using whatever is needed for your favorite langauge.

Comment: at least one decimal place looks too high, requiring custom type(higher than long double)

Comment: @l4m2 I could change it to +- 1 the correct answer.  Done

Comment: It's still out of long double. Usually a relative error bound is provided for such kind

Comment: @l4m2 I will keep it as it is.  There are plenty of clever people here who will enjoy the challenge ( I hope).

Comment: [Related: Möbius function](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/69993/the-m%c3%b6bius-function). We haven't had any logarithmic integral challenges yet as far as I could find.

Comment: Saying the solution shouldn't be fast but needs to not timeout on TIO is a bad rule in my opinion. If someone comes up with a valid, well-golfed solution that is slow, it shouldn't be invalid because it times out on TIO

Comment: Output within 1 of the correct answer - so 5.55 is a valid answer for \$i=1\$?

Comment: @jezza_99 yes it is a valid answer.

Comment: I agree with @l4m2, I think a relative error is much better than a blanket +-1. Otherwise the required accuracy of the solution increases with \$i\$

Comment: This challenge made me write [this thing to avoid when writing challenges: real-valued output with bad specification](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/25417/78410). Another thing to avoid: [requiring time limits](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20556/78410). The site culture is that *theoretically correct* solutions are fine, even if you can't see the results, as long as explanation is provided.

Comment: @l4m2 Everything should fit into a 128 bit float which gcc/llvm supports at least.

Comment: @Simd 1) *Computation* (add, multiply, whatever) with it doesn't necessarily give *that* accurate values. 2) You're requiring to use `__float128` or `Decimal` or equivalent in code golf, and these are dumb byte penalties where the same code would have worked using f64, just with less accurate results. 3) Many languages simply don't have such a thing.

Comment: @Bubbler the competition is per language so I don't see how the use of __float128 or whatever works for a particular language matters. You make an interesting point about precision. I wonder how much difference that will make here.

Answer (score 11):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 8 bytes

```
RiemannR
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7PygTyMnLC/ofUJSZV@KQ5mBokGBpyYXgoXNR@Bpg1XHGhpr/AQ)

Comment: It also asks a non-built-in solution

Comment: @Joao-3 That request was edited in after Adám's answer was submitted.

Comment: @chunes I understand, but LOOK!

Comment: The precision of this solution isn't high enough at 10^31. Something like [`Round@*RiemannR`](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7Pyi/NC/FQSsoEyiWlxf0P6AoM68kWlnXLi3a0CBOOTZWTUHfQSEoMS89NdrYMPY/AA) would satisfy the precision requirement.

Comment: @Roman Isn't that just a printing issue? I assume that the actual value that's returned has enough precision.

Comment: No, it's not a printing issue. `RiemannR[10.^31]` returns the machine-precision number ``1.421150973480811`*^29``, which is far off the mark (the error is about 2×10^14). You'd have to call it with an arbitrary-precision argument, like ``RiemannR[10`99^31]``, to get the correct answer. I'm not sure that's allowed by the rules.

Comment: @Roman I don't see why requiring that input form would be against default rules.

Comment: @Roman Thank you for spotting this.

Comment: You can abbreviate ``f@(10`99^31)`` with scientific notation as ``f@1`99*^31``

Comment: @att But that's just for calling the function; those bytes don't count.

Comment: Yes, it just irked me a bit ;)

Answer (score 11):

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 40 bytes

```
x->1+suminf(k=1,log(x)^k/k/k!/zeta(k+1))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMHiNAXbpaUlaboWNzUqdO0MtYtLczPz0jSybQ11cvLTNSo047L1gVBRvyq1JFEjW9tQUxOqXjctv0gjT8FWwVBHwRiIC4oy80o0lAwN4pQU8hSUFHTtgESaBpCfpwnTtGABhAYA)

Using the [Gram series](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1506980/99103).

Comment: An excellent answer benefitting from pari’s strengths.

Answer (score 9):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>193 183 173 165 154 145</s> 144 bytes

```c
typedef _Float128 X;X logq();i,k;r(X x,X*y){for(X a=*y=k=1,q;i=999,k<i;*y-=(ldexp(a*=logq(x)/k++,-k)-a)/q)for(q=0;--i;)q+=(i%2?k:-k)*pow(i,~k);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY7LToRAEEX3fEVlDKYLumcGZiM2rTv37lgYTYfXVJpXI0bIBD9dBBJXVZVzb@WkokzTZRmmLs/yAj5eqlYPQfgAiUygakvLUBI3smcJjDzxJrwV7XZo5U3KqIBbSSqKIm5ikt4kFKuyfOyY9tReH/FkfJ8Lg0LjyeLWtuoshSCJ1leM3PDZPK7c69pvRvzHoJyXO6q7th9i@6WzWg/X4/XJqTU1DG8ObD@oGYBUICm@hJJ8H2EFAAlMcps9WyUsI2@XCM6IHO4n3FnXr@WCHYLzu5uBe7yEr8Vbc@DEYU/Mzrz8pkWly89FVP8G61r/AQ)

This estimates the Riemann R function from the Gram series. Note that this uses a horribly obfuscated but faster converging implementation of the Riemann zeta function.

$$\zeta(s)=\frac{1}{1-2^{1-s}}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^s}$$

-1 thanks to @Simd. -8 thanks to @c--.

Slightly golfed less:

```c
typedef _Float128 X;
X logq();
i,k;
r(X x,X*y){
  for(X a=*y=k=1,q;i=999,k<i;){
    /* estimate the Riemann zeta function */
    for(q=0;--i;)
      q+=(i%2?k:-k)*pow(i,~k);
    *y-=(ldexp(a*=logq(x)/k++,-k)-a)/q
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow. This is amazing.

Comment: How about _Float128 instead of __float128?

Comment: It doesn't help with the golfing but it seems 99 can be reduced to 23.

Comment: The answer for 10^1 is not accurate to the required precision.

Comment: the algo for 999 cicles of the loop not go out than 4 digits after the "," example 16       279238341360977.187230253927299
10^16 279238341360977.187244069148541155

Comment: for me there is a problem of convergenct

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 44 bytes

```
Þ∞KƛƛÞ∞K$›eĖṠ2l≬₈vḞ≈c*n¡*?∆Lne$/;∑;2l≬₈vḞ≈c›
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLDnuKInkvGm8abw57iiJ5LJOKAumXEluG5oDJs4oms4oKIduG4nuKJiGMqbsKhKj/iiIZMbmUkLzviiJE7Mmziiazigoh24bie4omIY+KAuiIsIiIsIjEwIl0=)

I think this is correct. [Might be 38 if there's an exact limit convergance somehow](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLDnuKInkvGm8abw57iiJ5LJOKAumXEluG5oDJs4oG94omIYypuwqEqP+KIhkxuZSQvO+KIkTsybOKBveKJiGPigLoiLCIiLCIxMCJd).

Precision is met by having a) things evaluated to 256 decimal places when approximating and b) exact values used until an approximation is needed. Good luck getting this to return an actual answer in the time we have left in the universe. The algorithm should be correct though.

### Explained

The main idea to find the sums of things with an infinite upper bound is to check every overlapping pair of items in an infinite list of the sum applied from `1..1`, `1..2`, `1..3`, and so on until the pair has all the same items. This is basically checking for convergence manually.

```
Þ∞Kƛ...;2l≬₈vḞ≈c›
Þ∞Kƛ   ;          # Calculate the gram series for all possible upper bounds
        2l        # get all the overlapping pairs
          ≬₈vḞ≈c  #  and get the first where the items to 256 decimal places are the same
                › # increment
```

```
ƛÞ∞K$e›ĖṠ2l≬₈vḞ≈c*n¡*?∆Lne$/;∑  # Note that the context variable is set to whatever number in a prefix in the prefix is being gram seriesed is being zeta'd
 Þ∞K                            # To each prefix of an infinite list of positive integers
    $e›ĖṠ2l≬₈vḞ≈c                # Zeta function
                 *              # times k
                  n¡*           # times k!
                     ?∆Lne$/    # log(input) ** k divided by above
                            ;∑  # sum the result of apply to each k
```

```
$e›ĖṠ2l≬₈vḞ≈c # the top of the stack is the prefix list
$e›           # each number in each prefix to the power of k + 1
   Ė          # reciprocal of each number in each prefix
    Ṡ         # sum of each prefix
     2l       # overlapping pairs of sums
       ≬₈vḞ≈c # first item where pair is all the same to 256 decimal places.
```

Comment: The link seems to time out .

Comment: @simd it never will not time out.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python](https://www.python.org) + [SymPy](https://SymPy.org), <s>103</s> 99 bytes

```python
lambda x:1+Sum(ln(x)**k/k/gamma(k+1)/zeta(k+1),(k,1,oo)).evalf(50)
from sympy import*;k=Symbol('k')
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY27boMwFED3fsXdfK_jAKaqVKViz85aRXISTFy_kDEV9Fe6IEXtP_VvOpDpnOmc799hybcY1rtu3n-mrPevfxen_PmqYD7IXTt5dAFn4tyWtuyV9wrtTlL51eXNBFohRYxERfepnMaXip50ih7GxQ8LGD_ElPmbbdrFn6NDZhk9VkcdExgwAZIKfYdSPNd0GJIJGZlGkBWcmBhzQkOF-5jGjLVgwEgwgoYJjbLi3NCjt64b_wE) Takes ~30s on ATO for all 31 test cases.

- Thanks to Simd for posting [this chat message](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62679526#62679526)
- -4 thanks to ceilingcat

Comment: What do you get if you implement zeta too?

Comment: @Simd sorry, I don't know much about SymPy. What do mean by that?

Comment: You are using the function zeta from sympy. I was just wondering how much longer the code would be if you implemented zeta yourself.

Comment: @Simd oh. I think we could have `f=lambda a:sum(m**-a for m in range(1,10**6))` (45 bytes) - inspired by [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/120026/114446)

Comment: That looks cool. Could you add that as an alternative answer?

Comment: @Simd I tried [this](https://staging.ato.pxeger.com/run?1=Tc69TsMwFIbhvVdxNp9z6pa4qAgFZWfviiq5ULfGf5HjoKaXwcoSqYJ74m6gIgPTtz3f-_HVDuWY4ngxzdNnX8zi_vvd67B70XCq1XzTB_QRT8TsbtCx0c8lZas9OuIzurkikuikkikRLfdv2htcVzQ7N5Oi6-7XCMwLDSZlCGAjZB0Pe1RSVcx3RDOTU4BuCO0ANrQpF35wzWYIu-RROEFT2eMVsP-B2xXVbbaxoDAIqoKtkF3JaGnpX_uu4EoKECQFQSOkweuhpckbx7_9AQ) but it times out on ATO, so I don't think it's a valid answer.

Comment: Does @ceilingcat's C answer help?

Answer (score 4):

## [Julia](https://julialang.org), <s>141 138 133 125</s> 81 bytes

```
h(x,a=big(1.))=1-sum(k->(a*=log(x)/k)/sum(n->(-1)^n/n/n^k,1:99)/k*(1-2^-k),a:200)
```

-44 thanks to @MarcMush

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYlBDsIgEADvfQXH3QaEraeS4MGDzyDBqBShYGqb8HvEmdvM@0jBUW1tgcqduQcPdEI0JL7HClFcwI0mFQ8VZUT5j7lHQWiz7NrISc9znyOQmKyIyJ2elML2KhsLhvSZBtb5bCHvKQNbgJS9Bn9Lxe0QEBkOz/xoPw)

Slightly less golfed.

```
function h(x)
  B=BigFloat
  a=y=B(1);
  for K=1:200
    q=0;
    k=B(K);
    for n=1:99
      q-=(-1)^n/n/n^k
    end;
    a*=log(x)/k;
    y+=a/q/k*(1-2^-k)
  end;
  y
end
```

## [Julia](https://julialang.org) using zeta() builtin, <s>209</s> 205 bytes

```
using Base.MPFR
function h(x)B=BigFloat;a=y=B(1);for K=1:187 k=B(K);a*=log(x)/k;z=B();ccall((:mpfr_zeta,:libmpfr),Int8,(Ref{BigFloat},Ref{BigFloat},Int8),z,k+1,Base.MPFR.ROUNDING_MODE[]);y+=a/k/z end;y end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY9LC8IwEITv/RU5ZjVYgwelIZfiAxEfFDyJSqxtjY2p1BRsxd9ek4OCe1iYYdj95lopKeizbauH1BkKxSPpLTfTyEsrHRtZaHTBTwh5KLOpKoRhgtc8xBRYWpRowWlAR0OUW2sBTHS4KjKb93PWWAtYHAulMA5u97Q8NokRJFDy5BSQuTYjgqMkfX2Pv8m/cgkgDcm7lPzIetF6uxrPV7Pjcj2e7PbA6i4Xfu43KNFnVrvdOjhp4QbUQ3bupdRGaWzL0P7h@wBLAASey38A)

Slightly golfed less.

```
using Base.MPFR
function h(x)
  B=BigFloat;
  a=y=B(1);
  for K=1:187
    k=B(K);
    a*=log(x)/k;
    z=B();
    ccall((:mpfr_zeta,:libmpfr),Int8,(Ref{BigFloat},Ref{BigFloat},Int8),z,k+1,Base.MPFR.ROUNDING_MODE[]);
    y+=a/k/z
  end;
  y
end
```

Comment: Now Rust please ….

Comment: @Simd I haven’t quite worked out how to use `f128` in TIO or ATO.

Comment: This is not right for 10^1 .

Comment: The new version works!

Comment: 81 bytes, mainly by replacing the for loops with sums [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYlBDsIgEADvfQXH3QaEraeS4MGDzyDBqBShYGqb8HvEmdvM@0jBUW1tgcqduQcPdEI0JL7HClFcwI0mFQ8VZUT5j7lHQWiz7NrISc9znyOQmKyIyJ2elML2KhsLhvSZBtb5bCHvKQNbgJS9Bn9Lxe0QEBkOz/xoPw "Julia 1.0 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## [Python](https://www.python.org) + [mpmath](https://mpmath.org/), 28 bytes

```python
from mpmath import*
riemannr
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://staging.ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NY5BCsIwEEX3OcXsmoRakgoigjcRIWBrR8wkTKYLz-KmGz2FF_E2FkuX__F5_z_f-SFDoml6jdJv9p-eU4SYY5ABMObEYhVjFwMRL5XvKebmkgscYedUnxgQkIADXTvt621rDgogM5Loyjs4V_WcoQhrNM39NhbRrfmzVay9sxbNjMyysd75AQ)

### Not using the builtin, 84 bytes

```python
from mpmath import*
f=lambda x:1+nsum(lambda k:log(x)**k/k/fac(k)/zeta(k+1),[1,inf])
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://staging.ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NY9LCsIwFEXnXcWb-RJr2yiIFLoLHYlC_MTGNB_SV6huxUknuid3o0id3XMHB87jFW5UezcMz47UbPVeq-gt2GAl1aBt8JF4oqpG2sNJQl-KqWs7iyObsvEX7BnnJje5kkc0LL-fSaKZCpZuRaqd2rHRvbEhO4UWKlgWifIRNGgHUbrLGUW6mLMyAQhRO8KJKGA_Sb8MLUXULGuuXUs4Z79PoSg41-y7R_k_4AM)

Comment: Also works with mp.dps=30

Comment: What would you get it if you implemented zeta too?

Answer (score 2):

## APL(NARS), 330 chars

```
F←{0⌈(⌊1+10⍟⍵)-⍨⌊3.322÷⍨⎕fpc-1}

r←p z q;n;t;w;m;d;y;h;e
→2×⍳∼q=1⋄r←∞⋄→0
t←q×¯1v⋄r←q-q⋄e←÷10x*p⋄n←0v⋄w←1v
→7×⍳e>w×←0.5v
y←d←1v⋄h←n+1⋄m←0v
h-←1⋄y+←(t*⍨m+1)×d×←¯1×h÷m+←1⋄→5×⍳m<n
r+←w×y⋄n+←1⋄→3
r÷←1-2*1+t

r←R q;L;n;d;m;e;y
y←q×1v⋄r←1v⋄L←⍟y⋄n←0⋄d←1v⋄e←÷10x*2+F q
r+←m←(÷n×(⌊⎕fpc÷3.5)z n+1)×d×←L÷n+←1⋄→2×⍳e<∣m

⍪{{⍵⍕⍨1⌈¯8+F⍵}R⍵}¨10v*1..31
```

32+ 24+16+33+14+18+38+15+10 +18+39+45 +28=330

z should be the Riemann Zeta function that stop calc until p digits
after the decimal point, with input one number that should be
integer, float, big float,complex, big float clomplex and one output that
has to be big float or big float complex (I'm not sure of this speech 100%).
It seems if the number is not a complex the calculation in z function is done
not use complex operations but only float or big float operations. I'm not sure is safe to use ∞ as result for zeta in case input 1.

R it seems to be the Riemann R function cut on the possible digits
it can reach from the instruction (⌊⎕fpc÷4.1) for speed reason,
seen what the question ask too.

It seems:

1. ⎕fpc it is the lenght in bit of the float point number of type "NumbeRv"
2. ⌊1+10⍟⍵ it should be the lenght in decimal digit of the integer part of number in ⍵
3. ⌊3.322÷⍨⎕fpc-1 it should be the lenght in decimal digit of each float type "NumbeRv"
4. F ⍵ it should be the max lenght in decimal digit of fractional part number in ⍵,
   so it is the right place where end the computation
5. It seems is asked one decimal ¯8 + teoretical possible 128 bit precision for the calculus and for
   show the number
6. In function (r←p z q), if it was used the instruction r←q-q
   the calculation in z not use big complex float, but only big float
7. It seems 2+F q is safe as precision for R q (not for all other numbers return z function in R)

   ```
      ⍪{{⍵⍕⍨1⌈¯8+F⍵}R⍵}¨10v*1..31
   ```

   4.56458314100509023986577469558
   25.6616332669241825932267979404
   168.359446281167348064913310987
   1226.93121834343310855421625817
   9587.43173884197341435161292391
   78527.3994291277048588702921410
   664667.447564747767985346699888
   5761551.86732016956230886495974
   50847455.4277214275139488757726
   455050683.306846924463153241582
   4118052494.63140044176104610771
   37607910542.2259102347456960174
   346065531065.826027197892925730
   3204941731601.68903475050075412
   29844570495886.9273782222867278
   279238341360977.187230253927299
   2623557157055978.00387546001566
   24739954284239494.4025216514448
   234057667300228940.234656688561
   2220819602556027015.40121759224
   21127269485932299723.7338640440
   201467286689188773625.159011875
   1925320391607837268776.08025287
   18435599767347541878146.8033590
   176846309399141934626965.830969
   1699246750872419991992147.22186
   16352460426841662910939464.5782
   157589269275973235652219770.569
   1520698109714271830281953370.16
   14692398897720432716641650390.6
   142115097348080886394439772958.2

one calculation that takes 15' here...
it is possible change the number of bit of big float for to have

```
   ⎕fpc←64
   ⍪{{⍵⍕⍨F⍵}R⍵}¨10v*⍳3
4.56458314100509191 
25.6616332669242044 
168.359446281167561
```

with the last 3 or 4 decimal digits wrong it seems for the instruction
(⌊⎕fpc÷4.1) that should be (⌊⎕fpc÷3.322) for to have what it seems to me
the exact solution (with about 2x the time for calculus here some second
only for this)

```
   ⍪{{⍵⍕⍨F⍵}R⍵}¨10v*⍳3
4.56458314100509024 
25.6616332669241826 
168.359446281167348
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 354 bytes

```c
#include <quadmath.h>
#define D __float128
#define U unsigned
D Z(U p,D q){D t=-q,y,d,r,w,e,h;U n,m;for(r=n=0,w=1,e=w/powq(10,p);(w*=0.5q)>e;++n,r+=w*y)for(y=d=m=1,h=n;m<=n;--h,++m)y+=powq(m+1,t)*(d*=-h/m);return r/=1-powq(2,1+t);}D Rr(D q){D r,l,d,e,m,n;for(m=d=r=n=1,l=logq(q),e=r/powq(10,31);e<fabsq(m);++n,r+=m)m=(d*=l/n)*(1/(n*Z(31,n+1)));return r;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZJRb9owEMff8ylOqZDs5AI2bFo14@4BVIk3hsRLtw55JCGREkOcAEWoX33sAm1WaS9RfPbd/e7/v3W0Wa8vl7vcrot9nMC42pu4NE3Wzx68uzhJc5vAFFartNiaRg7vu@AS9rbONzaJvSk8sSXscAoVP0@h0VGFJ4zR4RETzNQSLJYq3TrmtNUCj1pioo@D3fZYMSlwxxU7Blr0P1f8IVFhaNGF@hiceJtz0rEuKSPTVpVj@kRRhmFY8lOorxXKUGLDAxYHOsoGJVcuafbOghtoGV1fDFGGDVevU1g49kbpsCDEBEu0V7SS2rR4EgtdbDcVqzhBug5yJLlKxqn5XVNH/g5Z8lK3jYuBJQI5YDZ4YiOJNpSc/yNRrx8krps4337UdwJwUxLWmXFdeAaQ26Y7LgBu5brIIwCRd8c5wM5RRup5M5jP2SQwOAnSsiFjDtw7z4hjAsa5H1JI8ay867941kI5/e77qra3IowuUQohsK1w4CpPmRsLvqAqHsHMmd@re7WPBuklV95r2zaNN01NEr@0Eh/06D6ixdk6siAkUaWo2E3Bl1adBRzGWnwTX9mMH9Q1vzS5ZcQ6BYOOFifviIefWuJHlpNDhpDz8WhILuT8bPSbR31RYU6ia3LZcEWEC4r@6g333G8v/h/N7/X6vfh76uMN3PHoCyVSpvbbsdBdy/y0Pm1PO7Vo57z8WaeF2dSXqHiX7S8)

This should be the port with some change of APL NARS answer... a little long.
Here printf can not print the number so it was need PP() for print in the screen the number.
I minimize the function Rr and Z, skipping all ceck for arguments, but it seems take more than 1 minute so no result showed from the link...

This below is the version ungolfed, more long (only for 128 bit floats too) that ceck arguments
but faster than above, and use the function Zeta could be right even for complex not only for the real part. 10 second is the run, so it is showed the result.

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 616 bytes

```c
#include <quadmath.h>
#define U  unsigned
#define LD  __float128
#define CP __complex128
#define FM  FLT128_MAX
#define R   return
#define F   for
CP zeta(U p,CP q)
{CP t=-q,y,r,s[130],u;
 LD w,e,d,h;
 U  n,m,k;
 if(q==1||p>38)R FM;
 p+=p==0;k=2+p*3.322; // 38*3.322+2=128
 F(m=1,s[0]=0;m<k;++m)s[m]=cpowq(m,t);
 F(r=n=0,w=1,e=w/powq(10,p);(w*=0.5q)>e;++n,r+=w*y)
         F(y=d=m=1,h=n;m<=n;--h,++m)y+=(m+1>=k?cpowq(m+1,t):s[m+1])*(d*=-h/m);
 R r/=1-cpowq(2,1+t);
}
    
 LD Rr(LD q)
{LD r,l,d,e,m,t,n;
 F(m=d=r=n=1,l=logq(q),e=r/powq(10,31);e<fabsq(m);++n,r+=m) 
           m=(d*=l/n)*(1/(n*zeta(31,n+1)));
 R r;
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVNtb9owEP7OrzhRIdnEATvZtKrBVFMnJKRWYmiVJnUMpXmBiMQkToB2bf/62DnhZVX5ENuPz3fPc/cQ2Isg2O8vEhWkmzCCQbHxw8yvlr3lsHURRnGiIrgH2KgyWagoPGG33wDm8zhd@5VwLk/wzQTRYJ3lafT0Pz66Axjd/kBofvf15wmeAoCOqo1W50iE4rVuYaY/UeWTe8gZ7gvaesGlknbBnplm5YNw@YxtvJahsmMRC9kSD8hVsYytcJvEpJBSvL7mQ/eSTpEDgrklcym5t5KOlXfdnus4HvT74F42B8uRhjeMSCYFVuEzDM4GK8@yMlo@ZDMZ5OtdQTJWUc@EaakkZzsMjuSuX98JznLqkV1X8t7ngg4jfKyYtuSu@0xbcPyNyLMMpSmzlApr4Me2l8wUerYkySwxlKvrQzlLYMErJGCJGe2SsCvtZT8zFKag@1LYTZzDhGWIvdVl6t5MNcGv6R8umqXYqAg7VDHlNTJDaTQIlsp0vShIQVGJPilxBfWiQew/lsiCHpVkFM5CADJpGKV9hdREn6huPTpXMGUJSg8skdXeBGO3h4C2g2qZlL0A7PRoujrl2YtlFSZrY8QPcJo8HvHm8mg/gManECx9/e5qDJCo6h00wX2uEY2Pmep1DJMJuen67KYbZxXDrm2bqb2MUcQN@Fo/CC74zGtaYM61TbQ8CpmXqklM8JIJzjkzqbbUQ1PqAad1O@rXU5iQdqfslG3mM4ymDf52FjeGOFxUpZniEzVD3Er30sa/3lrjwC0cmuAFaSb0ZLo9he1A8mt@RcZ0673LlPmJIgc1mMln2ruH5CTK@XQUNSIJWsJHVcnAdXDsCX3x5cEUPV6whKJe9JZPPRQwRfR3x9nQtrn4qL7d6fQ64fe4zRotmtpf8CG@lG2jmuk6zS/VpgfC2Bh@aMX@bxCn/qLcn53yDw)

Comment: Why is this so much less golfed than the other C answer?

Comment: @ceilingcat ok very well

Comment: [244 bytes](https://tio.run/##XVFNb5tAEL37V6yIkHa9g/lIpLZaTyTLqD6BYsu3No0osAYJlrCYUMvyXw/dmjqHXFY7b968mTeTOoc0Hce7UqVVn@XLtk@yOjkWi@JxdpflslQ5CcnL96pJjn7wdRYSSUPSsnNINGRQg8IaM9ToQ45@7tz7LezhBAMUsBGy0bRXXXlQeUZiiMSA@VImv7uW1kxobmopzeZYNYeWtsxVzMnc12ZoaQCKmZhzd8/@qcS4R0@ccIMR0sHFgD3mgvMY9hyH@enKKTAWsRuJE8fNpMJ5BIr7jG3m6BSOY5I6P/ZaES0u483fmvyfMC0S/eF6RybqB/BEXnWpjnKmoRRbup4nsJ5HEJI3dl6T1Q/f871nPF@ExtsWXzo11dAV@J7nQQRvTJSS6qXHTAOxI0/Usju7syCBFROXOikVvW5XTJrBw/N1jcZsubwPhOH/VBZjGiW9evS9RQslY2AyOxP9soOeWQaBz80t217Y2VZaQA3MZJ38ocE3R1ZNo1tqbuB7LZ2uo5kRdL6YZ0sttGAF2gw3vqeySg7d6FQ3h@Zb/wU)